# Cell not being displayed - "no index path for table cell being reused"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: Storyboard printscreen]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Wall Delegate: caso 2")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("you1on1Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OneToOneCell
    let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("other1on1Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OneToOneCell

    let newMessage = messages[indexPath.row]

    if(newMessage.you == true){
        if let picture = imageYou { cell.profilePictureyou.image = picture }
        if let textmsg = newMessage.text {
            cell.messageTextYou.text = textmsg
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        if let picture = imageOther { cell1.profilePicture.image = picture }
        if let textmsg = newMessage.text { cell1.messageText.text = textmsg }
        return cell1
    }
```

I don't know what is the problem, this error is being showed up, however app is still running, but text is only displayed when I click on tableview with mouse on simulator - it is the first app I am developing and it is the first time I am using a table view with two different cell structure (however it is the same cell file). This is meant to be a chat.

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Rather than dequeuing two cells and only returning one, you should use your if statement to work out which cell type you need to dequeue and just dequeue that one and return it

Comment: Oh yea, of course, thank you for fast and accurate answer! Image is not showing yet though, do you see any reason for this?

Comment: Where do `imageYou` and `imageOther` come from?  Any chance they are nil?

Comment: Yes it was nil, I am already sleeping. Have a good night

Comment: And thank you once again!